# LDAP auth successful with additional characters

Tags: security, ldap

I have a service which uses a LDAP directory (anonymous bind) to get the users and their passwords in order to perform the authentication. The problem is that I've realized that I can login with a user even if I put characters after his password.

As an example let the password of *user1* be *passwd*. I mean that I can use the service if I type *user1* and *passwd* but I can also enter if I type *user1* and *passwdwdwd*. As long as the first characters are the real password I can enter although I type other characters after it.

On the other hand, If I type characters before the real password I cannot use the service.

We've installed OpenLDAP 2.4.26 in SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP2

The configuration of slapd is this one:

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/rfc2307bis.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/yast.schema
pidfile         /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
argsfile        /var/run/slapd/slapd.args

access to dn.base=""
        by * read

access to dn.base="cn=Subschema"
        by * read

access to attrs=userPassword,userPKCS12
        by self write
        by * auth

access to attrs=shadowLastChange
        by self write
        by * read

access to *
        by * read

loglevel 0
database bdb
suffix xxxxxxx
rootdn xxxxxxx
rootpw xxxxxxx
directory /ldap
checkpoint 1024 5
cachesize 10000
index objectClass,uidNumber,gidNumber eq
index member,mail eq,pres
index cn,displayname,uid,sn,givenname sub,eq,pres
```

Any ideas about what could be the problem?

Thank you very much

Regards,

Comment: Could you please provide details of your configuration (minus anything sensitive)?   What OS/distro, version of LDAP, etc?

Comment: Thank you very much. After editing the post I've enabled slapd debug mode but I only can see if slapd accepts requests with the real password and others with additional characters but nothing useful.

Comment: Reading through the openldap [change logs](http://www.openldap.org/software/release/changes.html) I do not see anything at first glance that matches this behavior, but this could also be a bug in a schema, perhaps yast.  Have you verified that you are on the most recent version of OpenLDAP for Suse?  It appears they are up to Enterprise Server **12 sp1**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem. My password (and other users') was stored by using *crypt* which, according to its [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt):

*By taking the lowest 7 bits of each of the first eight characters of the key, a 56-bit key is obtained*.

Since our passwords have 8 characters length *crypt* returns the same hash even if I type more characters after the correct password.

Thank you very much.

Best regards